# Resultados diferentes en distinct

Tags: oracle, sql

Tengo una consulta. En Oracle la columna **NUM_DISTINCT** de la tabla tabla **ALL_TAB_COLUMNS** que muestra la cantidad de valores distintos me arroja un número que si comparo con la siguiente sentencia, obtengo datos distintos:

```
select count(distinct(CUSTOMER)) from CONTACT
```

**Dato usando la tabla ALL_TAB_COLUMNS:** 23904256

**Dato usando query:** 24122992

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe dicha diferencia?

Quedo atento a una pronta ayuda.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son dos formas distintas de contar los registros de una tabla:

```
select count(distinct(CUSTOMER)) from CONTACT
```

Esta consulta ejecuta el "conteo" real inmediatamente, va a representar el número más preciso ya que refleja el estado al momento de la consulta.

Por otro lado hacer algo como esto:

```
select column_name, num_distinct
    from all_tab_columns
    where table_name = 'CONTACT'
          and column_name = 'CUSTOMER'
```

Es ir a buscar una información en una vista de sistema, no directamente a la tabla física. Esta vista refleja el estado de la tabla al momento en que se hubieran generado las últimas estadísticas (cuyos tiempos maneja el motor), que seguramente en una tabla con mucho movimiento o muchos registros producirá discrepancias con el primer método.